# Convert negative decimal to hexadecimal floating point

Tags: floating-point, hex, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert -75 to a hexadecimal floating point. This floating point consists of 1 sign bit, 5 exponent bits, 10 mantisse bits and bias = 15. I was able to convert -75 to F 0000E 4B00000000. But I'm not completely sure how the hidden bit system works in this hexadecimal notation? I suspect that it doesn't exist because there are 16 different hexadecimal digits (0-F) instead of 2 (0-1) in the binary system.

So here is what I did:

```
-75 -> sign = -, so sign-bit = F. 
75 -> hexadecimal value = 4B. 
Normalise -> 4,B . 10^(-1). 
Exponent -> -1 + bias = -1 + 15 = 14 => 0000E. 
The complete floating point becomes:  F 0000E 4B00000000.
```

Is this correct?

Comment: In what programming language are you trying to do this? You should probably include that in the text of your question and also as a tag.

Comment: What does "hexadecimal floating point" mean? The hexadecimal representation in IEEE-754 format is `C2960000` for `-75.0f` and `C052C00000000000` for `-75.0`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It's not for any programming language. It's a theoretical conversion. And I'm not looking for the hexadecimal representation in IEEE754, but in the system I described in my post. I know it's confusing, but I'd like to fully understand these conversions :). Thank you for your help so far

Comment: You are correct that the hidden bit only works for normalized binary floating point. It depends on the idea that a binary digit that is known not be zero must be one. I've used a hexadecimal floating point system and it did not have a hidden bit.

Comment: On the other hand, at least in the systems I've used, the sign bit is a single bit, not a hex digit.

Comment: OK, thank you very much :) That's possible, I wasn't sure about that either

Comment: More generally, you seem to have too many bits. The total width is 16 bits (1+5+10), which should only be four hex digits.

Comment: How did you get a negative unbiased exponent for a number whose absolute magnitude is greater that 16? I would have expected unbiased exponent 1 or 2 depending on where the hexadecimal point is presumed to be in the significand.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. It has to be 1. And I was also mistaken in the number of hexadecimal digits. I'll try to correct it and update my post later on. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patricia Shanahan already said in the comments to your question, it is not likely that "bit" is to be interpreted as a full hex digit. A bit is always a "**bi**nary digi**t**" as far as I know.

The format you describe is just 16 bits. That is 4 hex digits only.

In fact your format sounds exactly like [half-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), otherwise known as **binary16**.

I suggest you solve this as a binary problem first. You get 16 bits `bb...b`:

```
bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb
\  /\  / \  /\  /
 ¯¯  ¯¯   ¯¯  ¯¯
```

Then group the 16 binary digits into groups of four to get your four hex digits.

Disclaimer: We cannot know for sure what number format you have in mind, so my solution is kind of a qualified guess.

Comment: The only part of the number format that was not clear to me is where the hexadecimal point falls in the significand. That affects whether the unbiased exponent is one or two. The comments suggest the point is to the right of the most significant digit. The hexadecimal formats I've used had, when normalized, the most significant digit to the right of the hexadecimal point. See [BM Floating Point Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture)